# show that there is a set $ A_0 \subseteq A $ such that $ card(B) = card(A_0 ) \le card(A) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $A$ and $B$ be infinite sets such that there is a surjective function
$$ g: A \to B $$
Use Axiom of Choice to show that there is a set $ A' \subset A $ such that $ card (B) = card(A') \leq card(A) $

In my proof, I wanted to use axiom of choice to have $ f(A') = \max (A') $
This would mean I could have $ card(A') \leq card(B) $ and $ card(A') \geq card(B) $. This seems really wrong as $A'$ will have to be infinite and therefore doesn't have a maximum element by which I can constitute $f(A')$.

Comment: As a hint - what can you say about the inverse image f$(b)^{-1}$ for each $b \in B$?

Comment: $ f(b) ^-1 $ for each b in B is injective. I'm not getting the hint.

Comment: What's important is that $f(b)^{-1}$ is never empty because the function is surjective. There is always some element of $A$ in the inverse image. Can you use the axiom of choice from there to construct the subset of $A$ you're looking for?

Comment: Could you just say since $ g(b) ^-1 $ is never empty we can construct $ A' $ such that it includes all elements given in $ g(b)^-1 $ ?

Comment: That's exactly it. Every inverse image has an element to choose so you can pick one from each.

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is not ordered, there is no maximum element to talk about. Even if it is ordered, as you said, there might not be a maximum element (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$).

For each $b \in B$, since $f$ is surjective $f^{-1}(b)$ is non-empty. This means that $\prod_{b \in B}f^{-1}(b)$ is a Cartesian product of non-empty sets, so by AC is itself non-empty. Let $g \in \prod_{b \in B} f^{-1}(B)$ (so $g$ is a function mapping each $b$ to an element in $f^{-1}(b)$), and we have $g$ is an injective (why?) function from $B$ to $A$. Set $A'$ to be the image of $g$ and the result follows.